# Stochastically bounded random variable implicances

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

We have a random variable $Y_n$ stochastically bounded, so for each $\varepsilon \geq 0$ ,   $\exists$ a constant $K$ and a value $n_0 = n_0 (\varepsilon)$ such that  $P(\left | Y_n \right |\leq K) \geq 1- \varepsilon$ . So we now consider another random variable $X_n$, and we know:

$$ \frac{X_n}{Y_n} \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0 \textrm{ when }n \rightarrow \infty $$

And we want to prove:

$$ X_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0 \textrm{ when }n \rightarrow \infty $$

So i found out that [there is a question with a correct answer about this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3422269/66096), but that answer starts with this:

$\left | X_n \right | > \varepsilon$ implies that $\left | \frac{X_n}{Y_n} \right | \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{M}$ or $Y_n\geq M$. It says that we can prove this by contradiction but i do not understand how.

Comment: How would you start the proof by contradiction?

Comment: Sorry i have two mistakes in my last comment. I was saying that maybe for the first case $\left | X_n \right | \leq \varepsilon \frac{\left [ Y_n \right ]}{M}$ Given the fact that $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary that would be prooved by absurd because $\left | X_n \right | > \varepsilon$. That would be right?